# Matlab exponent error

Tags: matlab

`kp=k0*e^(-Ea/RT)%L/(mol·h)`

How to write this function in Matlab?

I am facing error like :

```
Undefined function or variable 'e'.

Error in ROPPLAapproximation (line 20)
kp=k0*e^(-Ea/RT)%L/(mol·h)
```

Comment: As the answers say, you should be using `exp`. But you could do it your way too by just defining a variable called `e` as `e=exp(1)`. Also watch out for `%`, that's for comments in Matlab. You need `mod`

Comment: Out of interest, how did you even make that `·` symbol, and what on earth would make you think you could use characters in Matlab that aren't on your keyboard??

Comment: @Dan I guess OP inputs it through other input methods e.g. Chinese. :P

Comment: @herohuyongtao oh right, I guess that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
kp = mod(k0*exp(-Ea/RT), L) / (mol*h)
```

In Matlab,

- [`exp()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/exp.html) for `e^`, i.e. exponential function
- [`mod()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) for `%`, i.e. modulo operator (`%` in Matlab is for [commenting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comments.html))
- `*` for `·` (whatever way you input it), i.e. multiplication

Answer (score 0):

Matlab has the function `exp()` for `e^...`. Also, the function `mod()` is used for remainders instead of the C-like `%` operator. DO as follows: `kp=mod(k0*exp(-Ea/RT), L)/(mol·h)`.

Comment: `%` in Matlab is for commenting, not for the modulo operator. You'll need the `mod` function for that. Not to mention that `·` isn't even on your keyboard - so I have a sneaky suspicion that Matab won't like it

Comment: @Dan. Good catch. I obviously did not test this :)